# Can Paperclip convert jpg/png images to webp format? If yes, how to use it while defining the style hash for paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, webp

I am using paperclip compression in my model and i want to convert the image into webp before uploading it to s3. But the conversion is not happening, I am still getting the png image when I am visiting the url of the image.

```
  class ImageTesting
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Paperclip::Glue

   has_attached_file :image, :processors => [:thumbnail, :compression],
  :styles => {
                :xxlarge_square => ["640x640>",  { lossless: true } , :webp],
                :xlarge_square => ["480x480>",  { lossless: true } , :webp],
                :large_square => ["240x240>",  { lossless: true } ,:webp]
              },
   :convert_options => {
      :all => '-quality 80'
    },

   :storage => :s3,
   :s3_credentials => 'xxx',
   :s3_host_name => 'xxx',
   :s3_host_alias => 'xxx',
   :url => ':s3_alias_url',
   :path => ":class/:attachment/:id/:style"

  field :image_file_name, type: String
  field :image_updated_at, type: DateTime
  field :image_content_type, type: String
  field :image_file_size, type: Integer
end
```

Answer (score 0):

try use `format: :webp` in your hash:

```
 has_attached_file :image, :processors => [:thumbnail, :compression],
   :styles => {
                 :xxlarge_square => ["640x640>",  { lossless: true, format: :webp }],
                 :xlarge_square => ["480x480>",  { lossless: true, format: :webp }],
                 :large_square => ["240x240>",  { lossless: true, format: :webp }]
               },
```

Comment: Still not working :( I am getting the same png format which I used while uploading.

Comment: Yeah I tried uploading them. No changes for jpg or png images and when i tried directly to upload a webp format image, paperclip gave me an error.     <Paperclip::Tempfile:/var/folders/lb/qkgkf1f11_37lx1tqwmbsnr00000gn/T/apple20150509-36060-tn65rv20150509-36060-1gocnpn.{:format=>:webp}> is not a supported image format. Sorry bub :():